# SSRS Parameters. Allowing "All" or "Null"

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

SSRS parameters are a pain. I want to be able to re-use reports for many different needs by allowing the users access to many different parameters and making them optional.

So, if I start out with code such as:

```
Select * from mytable myt
where myt.date between '1/1/2010' and '12/31/2010'
and year(myt.date) = '2010'
and myt.partnumber = 'XYZ-123'
```

I want those parameters to be optional so my first attempts were to make the parameters default to  null such as:

```
and (myt.partnumber = (@PartNumber) or (@PartNumber) is null)
```

That has problems because if the database fields in question are nullable then you will drop records because null does not equal null.

I then used code such as this:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @PartNumber AS VARCHAR(25)
SET @Year = '..All'
SET @BeginDate = '1/1/2005'
SET @EndDate = '12/31/2010'
SET @PartNumber = '..All'
SET @Year = '..All'

Select * from mytable myt
where (myt.date between (@BeginDate) and (@EndDate))
and (year(myt.date) =  (@Year) or (@Year) = '..All' )
and (myt.partnumber = (@PartNumber) or (@PartNumber) = '..All')
```

That doesn't work because Year(myt.date) is an integer and @Year is not.

So, here are my questions.

1. How can I make my dates optional? Is the best way to simply default them to dates outside of a practical range so I return all values?
2. What is the best way to handle the null or '..All' options to make my queries as readable as possible and allow my users to have optional parameters for most data types? I'd rather not use null for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your third code block.  It seems like your WHERE clause could be corrected to work with a non-int value.  The AND clause for the year line would look like this--not my best T-SQL, but it should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
and 1 = CASE @Year WHEN '..All' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN year ( myt.date )  = CONVERT ( int, @Year ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END
```

This will allow you to have a string value of '..All' or an int value.  Either will match correctly.  You can do the same with partnumber.

Comment: I thought about using case statements but the problem is that the SQL statement gets really verbose and confusing if I have 10 parameters and most of them are Case statements.

Comment: You could pick magic numbers for the year and partnumber (like -1) and then you don't need to cast or convert anything.  This allows you to use the second code block.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead and allow nulls, which indicates the filter should not be applied.  Then, you can use the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable myt
WHERE COALESCE(myt.date, '1/1/1900') between COALESCE(@BeginDate, myt.date, '1/1/1900') and COALESCE(@EndDate, myt.date, '1/1/1900')
    AND COALESCE(YEAR(myt.date), -1) = COALESCE(@Year, YEAR(myt.date), -1)
    AND COALESCE(myt.partnumber, -1) = COALESCE(@PartNumber, myt.partnumber, -1)
```

In summary, if any variable value is NULL, then compare the column value to itself, which effectively ignores the condition.  More specifically, when testing `myt.date`, if `@BeginDate` is NULL then set the lower range value equal to the `myt.date` value.  Do the same substitution with the `@EndDate` value.  Even, if both `@BeginDate` and `@EndDate` are NULL, the condition will be true.

A similar approach is used for `YEAR(myt.date)` and `myt.partnumber`.  If the variable value is NULL, then compare the column value to itself, which is always true.

UPDATE:
Added a default value to each `COALESCE` to handle the situation where the column value is NULL.

Comment: This doesn't work and was the first thing I tried (mentioned in the question.) The reason is that if one of my fields nullable and contains a null value, then the record isn't returned. 

For example: 
AND myt.partnumber = COALESCE(@PartNumber, myt.partnumber) 

if both myt.partnumber and @PartNumber are null then the join doesn't return that record.

Comment: David - I missed that.  But, I'm not giving up... not yet anyway.  Check the update where there's an additional value in each COALESCE.  Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this, the key is to fix your null parameters values to surrogate nulls, also since sql server supports short circuit evaluation, putting the null check should generally perform better.

```
Select * from mytable myt
where (myt.date between (@BeginDate) and (@EndDate))
and (@Year IS NULL OR COALESCE(myt.date,'1900') = @Year)
and (@PartNumber IS NULL OR ISNULL(myt.partnumber, '<NULL>') = (@PartNumber)
```